# Javascript prototype reflection function

Tags: javascript, clearscript

I'm not exactly sure of the name of what I'd like to do but it goes like this:

Currently, I have a bunch of variables in my javascript context that look like $A126 or $B15.

Before running, I have to load in all 9000 of these variables and their current values so later parts of the code can just reference $xxx for the value.

The preloading is not efficient at all and is causing a bottleneck.

As there is a substantial amount of code that uses this $xxx notation I was wondering if it would be possible to make a universal change to   **$.xxx**  where $ is a function that performed a lookup of the value passed to it via what was after the period.

So $.xxx would be analogous to GetItem(xxx)

This is for a javascript environment in C# using clearscript, though I don't think that would impact the answer.

It looks like

```
   function Field(val){
    var value = val;

    this.__defineGetter__("xxx", function(){
        return value;
    });

    this.__defineSetter__("value2", function(val){
        value = val;
    });
}

var field = new Field("test");


console.log(field.xxx)
```

--->  'test'

That is almost an example of what I'm looking for.  The problem is that I would like to have a general **defineGetter** that doesn't look for a particular getter by name.

Comment: There is no method that gets called when you try to access a property of an object.  Why not make `$` a function, so you can do `$(xxx)` (instead of `$.xxx`)?

Comment: I'd try to avoid that as much as possible as doing a search and replace thousands of instances of $xxx to $.xxx is much easier than $(xxx), but if that is my only option...

Comment: Note that it would probably also need to be `$('xxx')`.  As for the search/replace - you could do that with a regular expression

Comment: @Scottingham: There's no way to make JavaScript run `GetItem(xxx)` when you access `$.xxx`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: can's we make getters using Object.defineProperty that would run a function upon property access?

Comment: @dandavis: I don't know.  I didn't think you could, but I do recall seeing `get:` and `set:` somewhere in ES6, I think.  This might be possible after all.

Comment: @Scottingham: Turns out it *is* possible.  See this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get and this http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/

Comment: you can just say $=window; then use $.A126 to reach the var A126...

Comment: @dandavis: that won't work because it assumes I've declared A126 somewhere.  The point of this is that I would like to avoid having to do that.  $.A126 should kick off a function with 'A126' as the parameter...I'm looking at that example page but applying it is proving difficult at this hour in the day for me.